# what does `localhost` mean inside a iframe which load a remote site?

Tags: javascript, iframe

My website has an `iframe` tag points to a remote server `<iframe src="http://mydomain/index.html">`. Inside the `iframe`, there is a script tag loading a script from localhost: `<script src="http://localhost:8080/index.js">`. I am working on building the local `index.js` and serve it in my localhost not on the remote server. Whether the `localhost` used inside the iframe script tag points to my local server or the server in `mydomain`?

Comment: I suspect you will run afoul of cross-origin policies.

Answer (score 0):

'localhost' always refers to the server the code is running on. If you have a script that is trying to load from localhost, it means it's trying to pull a fill from your physical computer. If you leave that hard coded to localhost and deploy the code elsewhere, that script won't load.

Incidentally, another way to refer to localhost is 127.0.0.1

Comment: I am facing exactly this issue. What could be a good way to always refer to the server's localhost?

Comment: By the fully qualified domain name.